# Why doesn't the "Rev" drop-down do anything?

Tags: bug, edits

When someone edits a post on Stack Exchange, there's a dropdown menu that says "Revision", the editor, the time, and a note.

[image]

But that dropdown menu does nothing at all. This is what the current revision looks like:

[image]

I select from the menu:

[image]

Now here it is:

[image]

That was just an example. I tried to revert my edit on my own posts, and the revision dropdown does nothing. So to revert my own post, I have to manually type it again.

Is there a reputation requirement? If so, why can't I use the dropdown on my own posts?

Comment: You can always find the revision linked in the edit history below the post, then rollback to the appropriate revision. And I believe the purpose of the drop-down is to somehow integrate diffs better. That said, this is puzzling.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's reporting a bug with the dropdown.